# Why is this not a dangling reference?

Tags: rust

I am following the second edition of the [TRPL book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/) (second edition) and am a little confused by one of the tasks. At the end of [section 10.2](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-02-traits.html#fixing-the-largest-function-with-trait-bounds) (Traits) I am asked to reimplement the `largest` function using the `Clone` trait. (Note that at this point I have not learned anything about lifetimes yet.) I implemented the following

```
fn largest<T: PartialOrd + Clone>(list: &[T]) -> &T {
    let l = list.clone();
    let mut largest = &l[0];

    for item in l {
        if item > &largest {
            largest = item;
        }
    }

    largest
}
```

This returns a reference to an item of the cloned list. And, lo and behold, it compiles. Why is this not a dangling reference (as described in [section 4.2](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#dangling-references))?

As far as I understand it, `largest` contains a reference to an item of a  (cloned) copy of `list`, but should `l` not go out of scope and thus invalidate the reference after `largest` has finished?

Comment: Matthieu's answer is correct; this works, because the lifetime-explicit signature of your function is basically `fn largest<'a, T: PartialOrd + Clone>(list: &'a [T]) -> &'a T`.

Comment: Thank you @ljedrz I will revisit this after the next chapter, but if I infer correctly what is means, then my output shares a lifetime (`'a`) with the reference to list that I put in (and is available as long as the input is still alive), right?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `l` does not have the type you think it does:

```
fn largest<T: PartialOrd>(list: &[T]) -> &T {
    let l: &[T] = list.clone();
    let mut largest = &l[0];

    for item in l {
        if item > &largest {
            largest = item;
        }
    }

    largest
}
```

`l` is a *reference* too, cloning a slice actually just returns the slice itself, with the same lifetime.

Therefore it's perfectly fine to take references into the slice, and your return value borrows the original slice.

Comment: Thank you very much :) This helped me a lot. Also thank you for reminding me that I can use `let l: &[T]`.

Comment: @m00am: For debugging purposes, a useful trick is to use `let x: () = ...;` and then let the compiler tell you what the type is in the error message.