# Why isn't this a dangling pointer?

Tags: rust

I am working may way through the Rust book, and it has [this code snippet](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html):

```
fn first_word(s: &String) -> usize {
    let bytes = s.as_bytes();

    for (i, &item) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
        if item == b' ' {
            return i;
        }
    }

    s.len()
}
```

In the previous chapter, it was explained that

- the rust compiler prevents you from retaining references into objects after they go out of scope (a dangling reference), and
- variables go out of scope at the last moment they are mentioned (the example given of this showed the creation of both an immutable and mutable reference to the same object in the same block by ensuring that the immutable reference was not mentioned after the creation of the mutable reference).

To me, it looks like `bytes` is not referenced after the `for` line header (presumably the code associated with `bytes.iter().enumerate()` is executed just once before the loop starts, not on every loop iteration), so `&item` shouldn't be allowed to be a reference into any part of `bytes`. But I don't see any other object (is "object" the right rust terminology?) that it could be a reference into.

It's true that `s` is still in scope, but, well... does the compiler even remember the connection between `bytes` and `s` by the time the `for` loop rolls around? Indeed, even if I change the function to accept `bytes` directly, the compiler thinks things are hunky-dory:

```
fn first_word(bytes: &[u8]) -> usize {
    for (i, &item) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
        if item == b' ' {
            return i+1;
        }
    }

    0
}
```

Here no variables other than `i` or `item` is mentioned after the `for` loop header, so it *really* seems like `&item` can't be a reference into anything!

I looked at [this very similarly-titled question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47750234/why-is-this-not-a-dangling-reference). The comments and answers there suggest that there might be a lifetime argument which is keeping `bytes` alive, and proposed a way to ask the compiler what it thinks the type/lifetime is. I haven't learned about lifetimes yet, so I'm fumbling about in the dark a little, but I tried:

```
fn first_word<'x_lifetime>(s: &String) -> usize {
    let bytes = s.as_bytes();
    let x_variable: &'x_lifetime () = bytes;

    for (i, &item) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
        if item == b' ' {
            return i+1;
        }
    }

    0
}
```

However, the error, while indeed indicating that `bytes` is a `&[u8]`, which I understand, also seems to imply there's no extra lifetime information associated with `bytes`. I say this because the error includes lifetime information in the "expected" part but not in the "found" part. Here it is:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> test.rs:3:39
  |
3 |     let x_variable: &'x_lifetime () = bytes;
  |                     ---------------   ^^^^^ expected `()`, found slice `[u8]`
  |                     |
  |                     expected due to this
  |
  = note: expected reference `&'x_lifetime ()`
             found reference `&[u8]`
```

So what is going on here? Obviously some part of my reasoning is off, but what? Why isn't `item` a dangling reference?

Comment: For loops of course hold on to the iterable they are iterating over until the end of the loop. The wording in the Rust book isn't entirely accurate, but the reality is a bit too complex to put in a nice sentence. In general you can simply assume that variables are around as long as they are still needed, of course only within the current lexical scope.

Comment: Also note that the borrow checker does memorize the connection between `bytes` and `s`. Since `bytes` points to the same data, the reference will have the same lifetime.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Ahh... I guess I was assuming that the iterable itself would hold onto a reference to the thing it's iterating over (which, being `bytes`, still seems like it would lead to a dangling pointer). Are you saying that `iter()` (or `enumerate()`, I suppose) makes a copy of the thing it's iterating over?

Comment: @SvenMarnach And yes, I'm familiar with and appreciate the pedagogical white lie for simplicity's sake. I've done it plenty of times myself. I guess what I'm really asking is: which part(s) of this long chain of reasoning was the one with the white lie in it?

Comment: Orthogonally, I wish you an enjoyable journey with Rust!

Comment: _Variables go out of scope at the last moment they are mentioned_: Consider this example: `let a = 0; let b = &a; dbg!(*b);`. A literal reading of that phrase would mean that when `dbg!(*b)` is run, `a` is already out of scope, so `b` is a dangling reference. I think you should say instead _Variables go out of scope at the last moment they are used_. But even then, that _used_ word is too vague to sum up all the non-lexical-lifetimes complexity.

Comment: No time to reply in detail, but I recommend reading [this blog post on non-lexical lifetimes](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2017/02/21/non-lexical-lifetimes-using-liveness-and-location/), which may clear up some of your questions.

Comment: @DanielWagner it's that they go out of scope *at the last moment they are mentioned*, that's a bit too eager. In reality, while they're considered dead *after* their last use and can potentially be reset/replaced, unless otherwise necessary they go out of scope at the end of their enclosing block (or when they're moved from if non-Copy).

Comment: I would refer to ch04-02, where it says "a reference’s scope starts from where it is introduced and continues through the last time that reference is used". Here, "is used" means, roughly, "is needed". Since the reference to `bytes` needs to persist within the loop body, Rust keeps it alive for (at least) that long. In other words, Rust is smart enough to compute use of a reference recursively instead of merely lexically -- `item == b' '` needs `&item` needs `bytes.iter().enumerate()` needs `bytes.iter()` needs `bytes`, so those references are all kept valid for the loop body.

Comment: These are all wonderful and enlightening comments, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a version of the first function with *all* the lifetimes and types included, and the `for` loop replaced with an equivalent `while let` loop.

```rust
fn first_word<'a>(s: &'a String) -> usize {
    let bytes: &'a [u8] = s.as_bytes();

    let mut iter: std::iter::Enumerate<std::slice::Iter<'a, u8>>
        = bytes.iter().enumerate();

    while let Some(iter_item) = iter.next() {
        let (i, &item): (usize, &'a u8) = iter_item;
        if item == b' ' {
            return i;
        }
    }

    s.len()
}
```

Things to notice here:

- The type of the iterator produced by `bytes.iter().enumerate()` has a lifetime parameter which ensures the iterator does not outlive the `[u8]` it iterates over. (Note that the `&[u8]` *can* go away — it isn't needed. What matters is that its *referent,* the bytes inside the `String`, stays alive. So, we only really need to think about one lifetime `'a`, not separate lifetimes for `s` and `bytes`, because there's only one byte-slice inside the `String` that we're referring to in different ways.
- `iter` — an explicit variable corresponding to the implicit action of `for` — is used *in every iteration* of the loop.

I see another misunderstanding, not exactly about the lifetimes and scope:

> there might be a lifetime argument which is keeping `bytes` alive,

**Lifetimes never keep something alive.** Lifetimes never affect the *execution* of the program; they never affect when something is dropped or deallocated. A lifetime in some type such as `&'a u8` is a compile-time *claim that values of that type will be valid for that lifetime*. Changing the lifetimes in a program changes only *what is to be proven (checked) by the compiler*, not *what is true about the program*.